# how to keep soft keyboard open when back button pressed

Tags: android, keyboard

I have method like this :

```
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        return false;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

But this is not working for me, how to keep soft keyboard still open though back key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can specialize EditText widget by overriding onKeyPreIme method to handle the back key.

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean retVal = false;

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            manager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Then use this specialized EditText widget in your Activity. The fragment layout snippet that I'm using.

```
 <com.example.MyEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: it same, not working for me, in first back key pressed, keyboard still hide, and when i pressed it again, keyboard show up and application quit.